# 'Return false' doesn't stop characters from appearing when input is checked against string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have the following code where I'm trying to check whether the user's input is among the accepted characters I have set.

**Code:**

```
element.onkeypress = function (e) {
    var
        key = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
        isAccepted = (typeof self.acceptedChars === "object") ?
            self.acceptedChars.test(key) : /* Check for RegEx */
            ~self.acceptedChars.indexOf(key), /* Check for String */
        isMaxOrLess = self.maxLength > this.value.length;
    if (isAccepted && isMaxOrLess) element.dispatchEvent(success);
    else if (!isAccepted && isMaxOrLess) element.dispatchEvent(error);
    return isAccepted && isMaxOrLess;
};
```

**Example:**

**[Working]**: If **`self.acceptedChars = /[a-z]/`**, then everything will run as expected producing the following:

- Input: **`ad12s`**
- Output: **`ads`**

**[NOT Working]**: If **`self.acceptedChars = "abc"`**, then even though all the characters except **`'a'`**, **`'b'`** and **`'c'`** will be recognised as not accepted, for some reason they can still be entered.

- Input: **`aabb12`**
- Output: **`aabb12`**
- Should have been: **`aabb`**

**Note:** The custom events **`success`** and **`error`** are used to display different messages based on the **`isMaxOrLess`** and **`isAccepted`** conditions and have no relation to the issue occurred.

Essentially my issue is that **`return false`** doesn't stop the characters from appearing when the **`acceptedChars`** is a string. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What does the tilde do before the key? `~key.indexOf`

Comment: In this case, it turns **`!= -1`** to **`>= 0`** @TamasRev

Comment: @TamasRev It converts -1 to falsy (0) leaving other values truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6oby07t1/).

```
!!~self.acceptedChars.indexOf(key), /* Check for String */
```

Not

```
~key.indexOf(self.acceptedChars), /* Check for String */
```

**UPD** You need to convert value to a boolean. Not just make it falsy

So better use less criptic

```
self.acceptedChars.indexOf(key) >= 0, /* Check for String */
```

Comment: @AngelPolitis I have updated the answer.. You need to convert return value to a boolean.

Comment: Nah, the more cryptic the better for me. I'll stick **`!!~`**. Thanks @Yury

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
element.onkeypress = function (e) {
    var
        key = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
        isAccepted = (typeof self.acceptedChars === "object") ?
            self.acceptedChars.test(key) : /* Check for RegEx */
            self.acceptedChars.indexOf(key) === -1 ? false : true, /* Check for String */
        isMaxOrLess = self.maxLength > this.value.length;
    if (isAccepted && isMaxOrLess) element.dispatchEvent(success);
    else if (!isAccepted && isMaxOrLess) element.dispatchEvent(error);
    return isAccepted && isMaxOrLess;
};
```

in case that self.acceptedChars is string you should return true/false values.

Comment: I believe your solution works as well, but why use a second ternary for something so simple?